# Ordering xamarin forms observable collection

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In xamarin forms do I have a Oberservable collection of wordpress posts.

I want to sort this collection by a specific value within this collection?

How am I able to do so in Xamarin forms / c# ?

I can see somewhere are people using:

```
list.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

But this does not use a Observable collection or a specific value from this collection to sort.

The fill of my object is this:

```
FlowObservableCollection<RootObject2> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlowObservableCollection<RootObject2>>(await posts.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Does anyone have a solution for sorting my array?

My value I wanna sort by is a sub value like: mycollection.group.Myvalue

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you could tell me on what basis do you want to sort this collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with `FlowObservableCollection<T>` but from what I could find it seems to be a subtype of `ObservableCollection<T>`<sup>[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)</sup>.

Since `ObservableCollection<T>` itself is a subtype of `Collection<T>` and therefore implements `IEnumerable<T>` you should not have any problem using its [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#extension-methods), e.g. `OrderBy`.

> I can see somewhere are people using:
>
> `list.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();`
>
> My value I wanna sort by is a sub value like: mycollection.group.Myvalue

Are you familiar with [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) as used in the [LINQ query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) of your `OrderByDescending()` example?

In case your not, in `list.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();` the term `x` refers to an element in the list and what your specify to the right of the `=>` arrow is your key for ordering.

So if you wanto to order by a different value you could simply write something like `myCollection.OrderByDescending(x => x.MyProperty);` Note that you can use terms different from `x` as long as they are the same on both sides of the arrow, e.g. `myCollection.OrderByDescending(myElement => myElement.MyProperty);`

Finally note that the call to `myCollection.OrderByDescending()` returns a new `IEnumerable` with the elements found in `myCollection` and does not change `myCollection` itself.

You cannot cast `IEnumerable<T>` to `FlowObservableCollection<T>`. So if you need an ordered `FlowObservableCollection<T>` you have to instantiate a new one using your ordered `IEnumerable` as an input.

In your case this is what it might look like:

```
var orderedElements = myCollection.OrderByDescending(x => x.MyProperty); 
var orderedCollection = new FlowObservableCollection<RootObject2>(orderedElements);`
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, im trying to do this `FlowObservableCollection<RootObject2> test = (FlowObservableCollection<RootObject2>)result.OrderByDescending(x => x.acf.product_date_group.product_date);` but it says "specified cast is not available"

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
   Collection = new ObservableCollection(Collection.OrderBy(x=>x.Date).ToList());
```

Or adapt this method:

```
public static void Sort<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, Comparison<T> comparison)
{
    var sortableList = new List<T>(collection);
    sortableList.Sort(comparison);

    for (int i = 0; i < sortableList.Count; i++)
    {
        collection.Move(collection.IndexOf(sortableList[i]), i);
    }
}
```